# Yii 1.1.7 - cannot find gii page

Tags: php, url-routing, yii

I want to use Gii in Yii.  My protected/config/main.php for my first webapp has this part uncommented, as instructed in the Yii documentation to enable Gii (123.45.67.123 is my public IP address from the computer I am trying to access):

```
'modules'=>array(
            // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool
            'gii'=>array(
                    'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
                    'password'=>'123456',
                    // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
                    'ipFilters'=>array('123.45.67.123','127.0.0.1','::1'),
            ),
    ),
```

I also have the urlManager enabled in my protected/config/main.php by uncommenting the below:

```
// uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
            'urlManager'=>array(
                    'urlFormat'=>'path',
                    'rules'=>array(
                            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                    ),
            ),
```

When I go to my Yii site, for example, www.example.org, the basic Yii page is loaded fine.  When I do www.example.org/gii, I get a 404. When I go to www.example.org/index.php?r=gii, I get a 404.  Why is my Gii page not found?  I am using CentOS 5.6.

Comment: do you have the .htaccess file and mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: Yes, .htaccess and mod_rewrite are enabled on the Apache side.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

http://www.example.org/index.php/gii

It seems you have the same rules as I do for url.  If http://www.example.org brings you to your main yii webapp page then the above link should work.

You were going to http://www.example.org/gii which is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, that works!!!  Now this means I also get to keep my urlManager working for clean URL's! Thank you!

Comment: thanks! I also had clean urls on and was wondering why the heck it didn't work for me as shown on the tutorial using index.php?r=gii   ..:P

Comment: It's the little things that hold you up when you're first getting to know the framework.  Glad we have a good Yii community here to speed things up for you.

Comment: Whats more it's poorly written 'getting started' documents that slow you down even more. You follow their suggested route and it simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Im using urlManager like this for gii

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'cacheID' => false,
    //'caseSensitive' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'urlSuffix' => '/',
    'rules'=>array(
          'gii'=>'gii',
          'gii/<controller:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>',
          'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>', 
...
```

and it doesn't conflict with routes for other site pages

Comment: Unfortunately this did not have any effect.  Still cannot get gii to work with your code when I replaced it with yours.

Answer (score 2):

Can you post your entire urlManager block with @briiC.lv's code incorporated? It should work, it's pretty much the same as mine:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array( // remove gii for production:
        'gii'=>'gii',
        'gii/<controller:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>',
        'gii/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'gii/<controller>/<action>',
        'site/index'=>'/',
        '<controller:\w+>'=>'site/<controller>',
        '<filter:(proj|dept)>/<id:\d+>'=>'site/',
    ),
    'showScriptName'=>false,
),
```

If it still doesn't work, you might also want to post/link to your complete main.config file.

Comment: Unfortunately stackoverflow won't let me copy/paste my entire main.php file. Too many characters

It is still not working, even with briiC.Iv's code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with the urlManager desactivated? Just to see if gii itself it's working

Comment: PERFECT! Now gii works without the urlManager!  So how do I get urlManager working AND gii working?

Comment: The thing is that I know the urlManager is working (sort of) because my site pages looked like "www.example.org/site/about".  Now when I disabled urlManager, they look like index.php?r=site/page&view=about, but gii works!  It is as if urlManager does not know about the gii page.  Could this be a bug???

Comment: Refer to my answer below, user.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mod rewrite enabled and want to place the following in your htaccess file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1M
DirectoryIndex index.php

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

and add the following to the 'urlManager' array in your config/main.php file:

```
'showScriptName'=>false,
```

Will remove the index.php from your url and make sure to only display urls in the form of domain.com/controller/action

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to access www.example.org/gii until I added the following in my vhost config

```
<Directory /path/to/web/root>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have just had the same problem with the URL and Gii and i found out that i had written not the right IP Address. When i changed to the right one from the Network Statistics and then added the IP to the ipFilters of GII.

Hope that helps!